# Why does the number of equivalence classes of $r^n$ mod $p^k$ not depend on $k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am unable to understand why a bound claimed in *On normal numbers* (Pacific J. Math. 10(2): 661-672 (1960)) by Wolfgang Schmidt regarding the maximum number of elements falling in the same equivalence class in the *$n$ run* (i.e, the numbers $r,r^2,r^3 \dots r^n$) modulo $p^k$ is true (where $p$ is a prime and $r$ is any number such that $p \nmid r$).

Schmidt proves the following lemma (Lemma 4 in the paper) first and the bound in my question is obtained as a corollary of this lemma.

**Lemma**: Assume $p$ is a prime with $p \nmid r$. Then, the order $o(r,p^k)$ of $r$ modulo $p^k$ satisfies $o(r,p^k) \geq \alpha_7(r,p)p^k$.

In the above statement, $\alpha_7(r,p)$ is a constant which depends only on $r$ and $p$. The proof of the above lemma was convincing to me. However, then the author claims that the following is a corollary of the above:

**Corollary**: Let $n$ run through a residue system modulo $p^k$. Then, at most $\alpha_8(r,p)$ of the numbers $r^n$ will fall into the same residue class modulo $p^k$.

As per the notation defined in the paper $\alpha_8(r,p)$ is a constant that depends only on $r$ and $p$. The author seems to be suggesting that at most $\alpha_8(r,p)$ fraction of the numbers $r,r^2,r^3 \dots r^n$ falls into the same equivalence class modulo $p^k$, because otherwise the statement is clearly false. Even after assuming this, I am unable to understand why the above can be obtained as a corollary of the lemma because if the lemma is used to show the corollary, then the constant must depend on $k$ also. Here is my approach to proving the corollary using the lemma:

*Proof of the corollary:* Since $o(r,p^k) \geq \alpha_7(r,p)p^k$, the numbers $r^n$ mod $p^k$ *cycles* through at least $\alpha_7(r,p)p^k$ elements modulo $p^k$ and hence the number of elements falling into the same equivalence class modulo $p^k$ is at most $\frac{n}{\alpha_7(r,p)p^k}$.

However, the fraction here is clearly $\frac{1}{\alpha_7(r,p)p^k}$ which depends on $r,p$ and $k$. I would appreciate it if anyone can clarify the following questions:

1. What am I missing in my approach to prove the corollary from the lemma because of which I am unable to remove the dependence of the constant on $k$?
2. In case the corollary does not follow directly from the lemma as claimed in the paper, can it be shown in any other way?
3. If the bound in the corollary is false, what is the best bound that can be obtained for the number of elements in the same equivalence class?

Comment: Your formula $n/(\alpha_7(r,p)p^k)$, that $n$ is supposed to be the number of numbers $r^j$ that you're looking at as $j$ runs through a residue system mod $p^k$, and that number is $p^k$, not $n$. It cancels the $p^k$ in the denominator, and everything is fine and dandy.

Comment: I was under the impression that $n$ can arbitrary. But when $n$ runs through a residue system modulo $p^k$, the number of such $n$'s is exactly equal to $p^k$. Now I understand the claim. Thanks a lot for the clarification!